# Assignment Rules are not triggered when leads are created / updated using REST API

Tags: rest-api, leads, assignment-rules, rest-service

I am making REST calls to my org to create or update Cases and Leads.  Using Sforce-Auto-Assign: TRUE or FALSE, I am able to control the auto assignment rule execution on Case object but this same head is not honored for loading Leads.

Any immediate help on this would greatly help me. Am I missing something? Should we do anything else apart from adding the header in the REST call above?

Comment: this should work, what version are you using in the rest service invocation?